# Update controller $scope on factory change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a factory called Call, inside the controller I've got an array of Calls inside $scope. What I'm trying to do is update the Call object and have the $scope updated. I've tried using $on but I couldn't get it to work, and it was a little haxy even if I could....

**How do I update the $scope when the factory object has been modified?**

```
var ctiApp = angular.module('ctiApp', []);

ctiApp.controller('PhoneController', function($scope,$interval,$http,Call,$rootScope){
    $scope.calls = [

    ];


    $scope.dial = function(number){
        var call = new Call();
        call.dial(number);
        $scope.calls.push(call);
    }

});

// Factory
ctiApp.factory('Call',['$rootScope','$http', function($rootScope ,$http){
    var Call = function()  {
        this.channel='';
        this.uid='';
        this.time='00:00:00';
        this.state='connecting';
        this.callerid='';
    }

    Call.prototype.dial = function(number){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/url'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data.data.response==='Success'){
                    console.log('#CONNECTED');
                    this.state = 'connected';
                    this.time = '00:00:00';
                    this.uid = data.data.uniqueid;
                    this.channel = data.data.channel;
                    this.callerid = number;
                }
            });
    }
    return Call;
}]);
```

NOTE: I've ripped out most of the functionality out of these functions, that's why there is some $http, $interval, etc, still behind....

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't really the problem your having but another way create multiple instances of a class (e.g. your Call class) is to use the $controller service. This approach was recommended in the [Writing a Massive Angular App at Google NG Conf](http://youtu.be/62RvRQuMVyg?t=21m8s)  Talk.

Here is an example:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    instance1: {{ctrl.instance1}}
    instance2: {{ctrl.instance2}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Foo', function() {
    var Foo = function($log) {
        this.$log = $log;
        this.sampleField = 1;
    }

    Foo.prototype.increaseSampleField = function() {
        this.sampleField++;
        this.$log.info('sample field is now: ' + this.sampleField);            
    };

    return Foo;
}());

var myCtrl = function($controller) {
    this.instance1 = $controller('Foo');
    this.instance2 = $controller('Foo');
    this.instance2.increaseSampleField();
}
```

And here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/M2Phe/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually much simpler than it looked on the surface. I was originally updating the wrong this, and there is no need to use a trigger like service ($emit,$broadcast,$on, etc) to propagate changes.

The reason the function wasn't originally working was because this. was no longer referring to the Call object, but to the $http verb it was used in.

So amending the function looks like this:

```
Call.prototype.dial = function(number){
    var self=this;//This is key! 
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/url'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.data.response==='Success'){
                console.log('#CONNECTED');
                self.state = 'connected';
                self.time = '00:00:00';
                self.uid = data.data.uniqueid;
                self.channel = data.data.channel;
                self.callerid = number;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to declare a factory would be to return a function example:

```
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
return {
    sayHello: function(text){
        return "Factory says \"Hello " + text + "\"";
    },
    sayGoodbye: function(text){
        return "Factory says \"Goodbye " + text + "\"";
    }  
}               
});
```

Comment: That is what I initially used, but returning a Class instead was much easier. Didn't run into issues when using the new keyword.